# Launching GNU screen when opening terminal

Tags: ubuntu, gnu-screen, bashrc, i3

I want that every opened terminal would be launched with screen session.
Actually what I want is simply accomplished with following steps:

```
1. win+enter (open terminal in i3wm)
2. $ screen
```

I wanted to make this automatically and put

```
[[ $TERM != "screen" ]] && screen
```

inside `.bashrc`. As a side effect now I see a lot of bash processes is spawned (why??)

```
alexhop+ 19307  0.0  0.0  28276  3016 pts/0    S+   11:20   0:00 screen
alexhop+ 19308  2.5  0.4  59272 33572 ?        Rs   11:20   0:00 SCREEN
alexhop+ 19309  0.2  0.0  24084  5516 pts/2    Ss+  11:20   0:00 /bin/bash
alexhop+ 19322  0.2  0.0  24084  5456 pts/3    Ss+  11:20   0:00 /bin/bash
alexhop+ 19338  0.2  0.0  24084  5316 pts/4    Ss+  11:20   0:00 /bin/bash
alexhop+ 19354  0.2  0.0  24084  5452 pts/5    Ss+  11:20   0:00 /bin/bash
alexhop+ 19370  0.2  0.0  24084  5388 pts/6    Ss+  11:20   0:00 /bin/bash
alexhop+ 19386  0.2  0.0  24084  5356 pts/7    Ss+  11:20   0:00 /bin/bash
alexhop+ 19402  0.2  0.0  24084  5452 pts/8    Ss+  11:20   0:00 /bin/bash
alexhop+ 19418  0.2  0.0  24084  5436 pts/9    Ss+  11:20   0:00 /bin/bash
alexhop+ 19434  0.2  0.0  24084  5456 pts/10   Ss+  11:20   0:00 /bin/bash
alexhop+ 19450  0.2  0.0  24084  5396 pts/11   Ss+  11:20   0:00 /bin/bash
alexhop+ 19466  0.2  0.0  24084  5388 pts/12   Ss+  11:20   0:00 /bin/bash
alexhop+ 19482  0.2  0.0  24084  5388 pts/13   Ss+  11:20   0:00 /bin/bash
alexhop+ 19498  0.2  0.0  24084  5388 pts/14   Ss+  11:20   0:00 /bin/bash
alexhop+ 19514  0.2  0.0  24084  5384 pts/15   Ss+  11:20   0:00 /bin/bash
alexhop+ 19530  0.2  0.0  24084  5512 pts/16   Ss+  11:20   0:00 /bin/bash
alexhop+ 19546  0.2  0.0  24084  5388 pts/17   Ss+  11:20   0:00 /bin/bash
alexhop+ 19562  0.0  0.0  24084  5384 pts/18   Ss+  11:20   0:00 /bin/bash
alexhop+ 19578  0.2  0.0  24084  5436 pts/19   Ss+  11:20   0:00 /bin/bash
alexhop+ 19594  0.2  0.0  24084  5388 pts/20   Ss+  11:20   0:00 /bin/bash
alexhop+ 19610  0.3  0.0  24084  5384 pts/21   Ss+  11:20   0:00 /bin/bash
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Host system: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Comment: Is it possible that you aren't closing the screen sessions when exiting a terminal?

Comment: this bash forks appears immediately after I openning the terminal

Comment: what if you want to ssh in (or login on the console, or just open a new terminal, or ....) and attach to an existing `screen` session?    BTW, unless you're a long-time `screen` user, you may find `tmux` easier to work with (I used `screen` for many years and finally switched over to `tmux` a year or so ago....and have never looked back)

Comment: @cas hi, sorry, didn't catch the point - how this relates to big amount of bashes spawned? About tmux - maybe I will switch to it later, thanks.

Comment: it doesn't relate at all to the number of bash processes spawned. I wasn't addressing that.   My comment, as should be obvious, was about whether automatically starting `screen` in every terminal was a good idea or not.  IMO, "not".   There was also a minor aside about tmux as an alternative to screen, but mostly I was pointing out that what you want to do isn't necessarily a great idea.

Comment: the respawning problem is probably because something in your environment (.bashrc, /etc/profile, whatever) is setting TERM, causing the `[ $TERM != "screen" ]` test to be true (and therefore run another screen in the background).  screen runs your $SHELL inside itself, causing an endless loop of bash starting screen and screen starting bash.

Comment: Ok got it, thank you for help. I will check it. By the way, the only feature of screen i interested in is a non-mouse way of copying text from console / navigating console. You already mentioned tmux, but to me both of them looks like an overkill for this. Could you suggest an alternative? Thank you.

Comment: see https://serverfault.com/questions/377221/how-do-i-know-im-running-inside-a-linux-screen-or-not and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392618/how-can-i-tell-whether-im-in-a-screen for alternative ways to detect running inside `screen`.   checking for `[ -z "$STY" ]` looks pretty good at first glance.

Comment: can't think of anything else that can do non-mouse copy-paste.   unless you want to use something like `xsel` to take input from stdin and put it into the primary or secondary selection or into the clipboard (e.g. `echo foo | xsel -i` puts "foo" into the primary selection).   or copy from those to stdout.   that's not much good for interactive copy-paste though.

Comment: @cas looks like if [[ -z $STY ]]; then scree fi helps. You can post as an answer if you would like to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly happening because something in your environment (`.bashrc`, `/etc/profile`, whatever) is setting the TERM variable (e.g. something like `TERM=xterm`).

This causes the `[[ $TERM != "screen" ]]` test to evaluate as true, so another instance of screen is started.

screen then runs your $SHELL inside itself, causing an endless loop of `bash` starting `screen` and `screen` starting `bash`.

BTW, if `$TERM` isn't set properly before `screen` starts then `screen` will not know how to correctly work with the terminal it's running on.  So not setting it is not a good option.

There are several better ways to detect if a shell is running inside `screen`.  See [How do I know I'm running inside a linux “screen” or not?](https://serverfault.com/questions/377221/how-do-i-know-im-running-inside-a-linux-screen-or-not) and [How can I tell whether I'm in a screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392618/how-can-i-tell-whether-im-in-a-screen) for answers from some of the many other times this question has been asked on sister Stack Exchange sites.

Probably the easiest way is to test if the $STY variable is empty.  According to `man screen`, this variable is set by `screen` to hold the "Alternate socket name".

In other words, instead of:

```
[[ $TERM != "screen" ]] && screen
```

try this:

```
[ -z "$STY" ] && screen    # test if $STY is empty
```

or:

```
[ -n "$STY" ] || screen    # test if $STY is NOT empty.
```

You could use `[[ .... ]]` instead if you prefer. It makes little difference, except you wouldn't have to double-quote `$STY`.  IMO that's a bad habit to get into and you should quote it anyway because the situations where you **DO** have to double-quote your variables vastly outnumber the handful of special cases where you don't have to.

Comment: Usually **not** setting `TERM` from within the shell context is the best option. Terminal emulators (be they `xterm`, `screen` or anything else) should take care of setting `TERM` correctly themselves, as `TERM` is the way terminal emulators inform other applications about the terminal's capabilities.

Comment: The terminal emulator is included in the "whatever" part of "something in your environment is setting TERM".    It doesn't really matter what's setting TERM, the point is that using it as a proxy to detect `screen` was the problem here.    Also, sometimes there are good reasons for overriding what the terminal sets TERM to (e.g. to work around a buggy app, or to have your own custom xterm definition with stuff like ti/te disabled) - and most terminal emulator work reasonably well with almost any xterm- or vt100-like setting.